# how are functional specification for existing application called?

Tags: functional-specifications

what do you call a functional specification for existing application? I have an existing application and  I need to redo the application. It has no documentation for it, and I have been asked to write a functional breakdown spec. I have no problem breaking down the application, but I was looking for a document template to use .

Comment: How about "functional specification"?

Comment: Perhaps, you mean a [design doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_document)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [IEEE 1016-1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Design_Description): "IEEE 1016-1998, also known as the Recommended Practice for Software Design Descriptions, is an IEEE standard that specifies an organizational structure for a software design description (SDD). An SDD is a document used to specify system architecture and application design in a software related project."